# How do you make the dock more sensitive to being shown?

Tags: macos, dock, ui, customization

The amount that you have to move the mouse downwards to get the dock to trigger is too high in my opinion.  I've only found the following settings:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 0
```

This set the speed of the transition to 0, but does not make it easier to trigger.

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide-delay -float 0
```

This sets the delay to 0 once triggered, but does not make it easier to trigger.

I want it to launch the moment the mouse touches the edge of my screen.

Thanks

Edit: the suggested duplicate has no answers that answer this question as addressed in the text above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make auto-hide/show for the dock faster?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33600/how-can-i-make-auto-hide-show-for-the-dock-faster).

Comment: The second command achieves the desired effect.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure why but with that setup, it feels pretty easy to trigger dock show/hide for me. I found `0.4` suits me most.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -int 0
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 0.4
killall Dock
```

Comment: that looks like a Dupe from this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70598/46541

Comment: For some reason it requires me to drag my mouse/finger down even once I've reached the edge of the screen.  The extra drag drives me crazy.

It's much more noticeable with the mouse.

Comment: The second line is unnecessary. However, it does make it  feel faster

Comment: OMG thank you for this answer, this was bugging me!