# How to change just the Dock hide duration?

Tags: terminal, dock

Most people have seen the Terminal hack to change the Dock Hide/show duration in [How can I make auto-hide/show for the dock faster?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33600/how-can-i-make-auto-hide-show-for-the-dock-faster), but I was wondering if anyone has found how to set each of these to different speeds. For example, 0 second delay for the Dock to show upon mouse hover, but 1 second for it to autohide again.

Answer (score 4):

You can change two values for the Dock when it comes to the animation speed:

**autohide-delay**

```
# Dock autohide delay set to 0 seconds, the default should be around 1.0
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 0
```

---

**autohide-time-modifier**

```
# Dock animation duration to show/hide the Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 0
```

---

Set the first value to 0 and the second to 1.0 in order to achieve your result. It's not possible, however, to set separate durations for the hide delay and the show delay.