# How to speed up window minimising in MacOS?

Tags: macos, terminal

Minimising a window in MacOS takes too long for me. I sped up the dock autohiding by using these commands in Terminal: [How can I make auto-hide/show for the dock faster?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33600/how-can-i-make-auto-hide-show-for-the-dock-faster#34097)

Surely there's a way to make minimising windows faster too. Do any of you know what command I should use?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to switch off the "genie effect", if that's what you refer to.
Even though it's not the same thing, hiding the window can produce similar effect than minimizing. The fastest way to achieve this is to press cmd+h.

Comment: @user158589 Unfortunately that hides the entire app which may not necessarily be what the OP is after.

Comment: @Monomeeth Oh yeah, it does not work if you have more than one window open in the same app. But as a direct answer to actual question, I don't think there's a way to do exactly that. Feel ya, I'm not a fan of the fullscreen or spaces animations for example, but they're built in to the OS.